# Footer Links Jittering/Moving on Hover

Tags: html, css

I need some expert advice on this as its driving me crazy!!

I have checked through everything and even removed all CSS but I can’t stop this from happening!

In the footer of this website - [www.thedevelopists.co.uk](http://www.thedevelopists.co.uk), the links are moving downwards about 1px on hover. The crazy thing is though that they don’t bounce back up when you leave, they remain 1px down. Also, to see this error/bug, you have to be scrolled right to the bottom of the page??

If somebody could figure this out I will be so happy!!

P.S This is affected the most in Firefox. In Chrome it behaves a little differently, rather than moving slightly the curser hand flickers like crazy.

Comment: Looks normal to me in both Chrome and FF, I get a little text highlight animation on hover. What versions of the browsers are you using?

Comment: @DBS tried IE, looks allright too.

Comment: This is affected in Firefox only first time. Second time its look normal.

Comment: In my Chrome Version 51.0.2704.106 m and also in Firefox Developer Edition 49.0a2 (2016-07-03) its looks normal. So, how to know what's the problem is ?

Comment: that’s so weird! I’ve tried it on two different machines and it happens. Like Vishal Panara said, it happens only the first time, then you have to hard refresh the page and it does it again! I’m using the latest version of FF. So confused!

Comment: Vishal Panara - Why is it doing it even the first time?

Comment: Didnt work Teuta, thanks for trying though!

Comment: @dannyboi1987, it is very hard to verify the problem with inspect. Sometimes, when I remove line-height from footer, it seems to work. Try again to remove line height from footer!

Comment: removed all line heights, still same problem, I have never come across this before

Comment: One last try, in the above answer from @himanshu, add height: 28px and line-height: 28px

Comment: @dannyboi1987 can you post your all `a:hover` css code

Comment: still no good :-( thanks for trying

Answer (score 0):

It's quit simple. Just put below code in your css.

```
footer li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This is happen because your **li** is not clear. There for it happen. Cheers!!!

Comment: tried that mate still aint working, i left the css in there for you to see :-)

Comment: Can put your code here?@dannyboi1987

Which browser you used? I mean version of your browser. In my browser it's working fine like on hover opacity:0.4

Comment: its firefox that seems to be the main issue, what code do you want to see? its all just html, css that you can see in inspector? Do you want me to post footer html, css?

Comment: Something as simple as :hover shouldnt being different from browser version to browser version should it?

Comment: the curser is also behaving very strangely? Filckering from hand to arrow

Comment: Hover is not different to browser to browser. But some browser get extra space and they not clear that space itself. There for. I check in all major browser its working good. No moving links.If possible to do hard refresh. Then see what happen

Comment: ah ok, if its not effecting you guys then it must be an issue on my browser. cleared cache and hard refresh, still same problem. Thanks for your help

Comment: also add footer a {z-index: 1;}

Comment: This must be a bug guys. Try this! scroll down to the footer but NOT all the way down to the bottom, and the links will hover fine. But then if you hard refresh and DO scroll ALL the way to the bottom of the page the links mess up again!

Comment: add .list-inline>li{ width:auto;}

Comment: I dont understand why you give them height

Comment: I didnt, im just trying everything that people on here are telling me to do :-)

Comment: No need give height during text link like this.  :) @dannyboi1987

Its works fine check in other machine or update your browser version( try latest) and also check in other  browser. :)

Comment: ok, i think im gunna just have to try and ignore it! Thanks for your help

Comment: your welcome :)If its hepls you then mark correct or give +1 vote @dannyboi1987

Answer (score 0):

Try this code as you feel footer Links Jittering/Moving on Hover is due to transition effect

If do not need that

```
footer a { transition: none; }
```

Comment: should be there. Just notices something else, if i refresh the page hitting f5 for example, its fine! but if i hard refresh, the error starts again?

Comment: So the problem must be my browser